# Nginx - rewrite location to root (pgadmin4)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, pgadmin-4

I got this nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name my-pgadmin.local;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my-pgadmin.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my-pgadmin.local.key;
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /pgadmin4/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7070/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

On my browser, when I type : 'https://my-pgadmin.local' Im redirected to 'https://my-pgadmin.local/**pgadmin4/browser/**' which seems to be a static path.

How I can rewrite the URL to hide '/pgadmin4/browser' and have only 'https://my-pgadmin.local' ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to nginx, your counfiguration file is outdated. Use `listen 443 ssl` instead of using `ssl on`.

If security matters, you can enable HTTP/2 using this directive `http2 on`. Protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 aren't used anymore. TLSv1.2 can still be used, but it's recommended when strong ciphers are configured.

And here is answer to your question. **example.com** will be proxied to **example.com/pgadmin4/browser** and **example.com/pgadmin4/browser** to **example.com/pgadmin4/browser**. If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    sub_filter '/pgadmin4/browser/' '/';
    sub_filter_once off;

 
    location /pgadmin4/browser {
        proxy_pass http://express:3000/pgadmin4/browser/;
    }
    proxy_pass http://express:3000/pgadmin4/browser/;
}
```